# CMS for database oriented user projects

Tags: cms, database

I am looking for either a CMS or for some kind of database web view which for allows the following scenarios (self hosted):

- users can register etc
- users create an arbitrary number of data projects, where information is provided over several database tables, e.g. choose or create new product name. Upload different types of files per project
- users can view and edit their projects and the respective data, especially delete files or add some more
- the input is entered/uploaded in a single form, which then fills the different database tables

I'm pretty sure CMS like Wordpress, Drupal etc can be made to work like this, but it seems tedious. There must be more database oriented CMS to start with? I also found different direct web admin panels/web interfaces for databases but this seems too raw and complex for user interaction